# Can one work with any classes of numbers in a proof of number theory?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question

Can one work with any classes of numbers, like natural, integer, rational, real and complex, in a proof of number theory, as long as the result tells something about the integers ? Or should the result be proven using integer-operations only (we can only divide one integer by another if the quotient is an integer, because otherwise we fall out of the default domain) ?

To be more specific, should we stay inside the group of integers when proving results about the integers ? If not, we are proving the result in a larger group containing the integers as a subgroup ?

Comment: There are many important theorems of number theory in which we step outside the ordinary integers.

Comment: The Riemann zeta function is a complex-valued function which is quite useful in number theory. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

Comment: @AndréNicolas : so we prove theorems in number theory using rational,real or complex numbers often ? This also holds for elementary number theory ?

Comment: Elementary number theory is sometimes informally defined as not stepping outside the ordinary integers, though in every course I have taught I have at least dealt with Gaussian integers. Anyway, elementary number theory is a small part of number theory.

Comment: Ahh, thanks ! That was what made me confused ! - That my elementary number theory textbooks states at the beginning that we are dealing with integers. But in proofs we are allowed to extend the domain, I now know.

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth would you impose such restrictions? There's only one thing you should require of a proof: that it be logically valid. The end.

Not only is there absolutely no reason to apply a restriction like that, but modern number theory very frequently steps outside the realm of ordinary integers. [Analaytic number theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_number_theory) is roughly speaking the application of calculus to number theory, while [algebraic number theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_theory) uses systems of numbers that can include complex numbers (for example, the Gaussian integers $a+bi$ where $a,b$ are integers). I've often heard of something called [ergodic theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory) used in contemporary number theory, although I have no idea how or even what exactly that is.

Comment: For example congruences, binomial coefficients and the like are only defined for integers - that made me think my question.
Also, since every book states we are using integers I thought we assumed that integers only existed and not every other class of numbers.

Comment: @user111854 Binomial coefficients are only defined for integers, this is true. So if somebody tried to refer to $a\choose b$ and $a$ and $b$ weren't integers, you'd have a problem. But the proof isn't magically invalidated simply because the author *mentioned* something that wasn't an integer. Like I said, there's only one question you need to ask yourself: is what the author saying true?

Comment: Is Elementary Number Theory only defined for integers then ? In many books only properties and explanation of the integers are given ?

Comment: @user111854 The phrase "elementary number theory is defined only for integers" doesn't mean anything. I feel I must stress again that there isn't some hidden body of ordained esoteric rules that determines what is and is not valid in a proof. The only rule is the obvious one that everything in the proof has to be true.

Answer (score 1):

We need to introduce the natural numbers $\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,3,...\}$ and their basic properties [axiomatically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms). But then the integers $\Bbb Z$, the rationals $\Bbb Q$, the reals $\Bbb R$, the complex $\Bbb C$, the $p$-adics $\Bbb Q_p$ and all other "numbers" we deal with are constructed by means of relatively simple set-theoretic or algebraic-topological procedures which ultimately rely just on $\Bbb N$. Thus, all "classes of numbers" you can think of are, at bottom level, just "organized natural numbers".

Answer (score -1):

$$\text{Yes, only natural numbers!}$$
Says Kronecker.